# Missing Parameter Values

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm getting error 'Missing parameter values'. I have looked through many of the postings and tried them all.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PaystubParms pparms = new PaystubParms();

        pparms.periodstart = 20120316;
        pparms.periodend = 20120331;
        pparms.empno = "91065";
        pparms.checknbr = 2306;

        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("Abra_Reports","123456","Tsysmas","AbraHrms_Live");


        ParameterField pfield0 = PaystubCrystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo[0];
        ParameterDiscreteValue pfield0val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pfield0val.Value = pparms.periodstart;
        pfield0.CurrentValues.Add(pfield0val);
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ParameterField pfield1 = PaystubCrystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo[1];
        ParameterDiscreteValue pfield1val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pfield1val.Value = pparms.periodend;
        pfield1.CurrentValues.Add(pfield1val);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ParameterField pfield2 = PaystubCrystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo[2];
        ParameterDiscreteValue pfield2val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pfield2val.Value = pparms.empno;
        pfield2.CurrentValues.Add(pfield1val);
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ParameterField pfield3 = PaystubCrystalReportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo[3];
        ParameterDiscreteValue pfield3val = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        pfield3val.Value = pparms.periodstart;
        pfield3.CurrentValues.Add(pfield1val);



        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, pfield0.CurrentValues.Add(pfield0val));

        *******************************************************************
        I have also tried
        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, pparms.periodstart);
        *******************************************************************************

        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, pfield1.CurrentValues.Add(pfield1val));
        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(2, pfield2.CurrentValues.Add(pfield2val));
        PaystubCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(3, pfield3.CurrentValues.Add(pfield3val));

        PaystubCrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = PaystubCrystalReportSource;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all parameters are in the type that Crystal expects.

Sometimes passing a parameter of the wrong type can cause the "missing parameter" error. For example, passing a decimal value for an integer parameter.

Comment: Yes, I did make a mistake in the date parameters. I have since then cahnged it to  pparms.periodstart = DateTime.ParseExact("20120316", "yyyymmdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            pparms.periodend = DateTime.ParseExact("20120331", "yyyymmdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Comment: But it did not solve the problem. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I meant that in your crystal report, make sure that the types of parameters the report expects are the same types that you pass to it in your code.

Comment: The crystal report uses a T-SQL stored procedure that takes 3 input parameretes @startdate date,@enddate date,@empno varchar(7). The 4th parameter is from crystal itself - check nbr and is of type number. From asp.net I can only pass a datetime and not date. Not sure if that is the problem. I don't know how to to pass a date from asp.net.  Also, do the parameter names in asp.net have to match the parameter names in the Stored Procedure and Crystal? Thanks for all the help.